# How to prevent travis from deploying twice?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have travis set up to test using tox (Python 2.7 and 3.5) and deploy to pypi.

Travis tries to deploy the package for each test run, and pypi correctly rejects the second attempt.

I want travis to deploy *once* only when tox completes both runs successfully. How is this accomplished?

Travis config: https://github.com/biocommons/biocommons.seqrepo/blob/master/.travis.yml

And a test run: https://travis-ci.org/biocommons/biocommons.seqrepo/builds/157794212 (68.2 finished first and pushed to pypi. The pypi error is in 68.1.)

Related but stale question: [Why does Travis not wait for all builds to pass before deploying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524712/why-does-travis-not-wait-for-all-builds-to-pass-before-deploying)

Comment: I doubt you actually can as each job is independent

Comment: Really? Deploying on partial test success seems so unacceptable to me that I suspect someone's figured this out. (In fact, I'm surprised it's even possible to push on partial success.) It may be related to https://github.com/ryanhiebert/tox-travis/issues/13.

Comment: There's no "partial success", the only thing you know is whether *`this`* job succeeded

Comment: I am having this problem too. It's stupid my second build fails just because the first one succeeded to deploy.

Comment: Could you download the package (if exists), do a checksum and deploy only if different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can now be accomplished with [build stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages), which are currently in beta. This looks something like so:

```
stages:  # determines the order everything runs in
- test
- deploy
jobs:  #  specifies the actual job
  include:
    - stage: test
      # configuration for a stage here
    - stage: deploy
      # configuration for the next stage here
```

Given a `.travis.yml` like this:

```
language: python
sudo: false
cache: pip
python:
- 2.7
- 3.4
- 3.5
- 3.6
- pypy
install:
- pip install tox-travis
script:
- tox
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  user: stephenfin
  password:
    secure: <key omitted for brevity>
  on:
    tags: true
  distributions: sdist bdist_wheel
```

You would convert it like so:

```
language: python
sudo: false
cache: pip
python:
- 2.7
- 3.4
- 3.5
- 3.6
- pypy
install:
- pip install tox-travis
script:
- tox
stages:
- test
- deploy
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: deploy
      python: 3.6
      install: skip  # no tests, no depedencies needed
      script: skip  # we're not running tests
      deploy:
        provider: pypi
        user: stephenfin
        password:
          secure: <key omitted for brevity>
        on:
          tags: true
        distributions: sdist bdist_wheel
```

Personally, I found this a little counterintuitive: I expected everything that wasn't *global* to be nested under a `stage`. As a result, I had explicitly defined the `test` stage and nested the `python`, `install` and `script` keys under there. However, this doesn't work and you instead need to set those keys in the top level and then explicitly override them in individual stages. The global stuff will be called by the `test` stage, which is the default job. I've not yet determined if this is an issue with Travis or the `tox-travis` plugin (currently 0.10), but it's worth calling out.

Also note that if you're using the Travis Gem, the `travis lint` command currently fails because this feature is not supported there yet. There's a [bug](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/issues/571) open for this.

Comment: Here's another example of a before-and-after diff that might help others: https://github.com/biocommons/hgvs/commit/5f74cdd12bb844f0d955ed360071c5c2faac117c